# Running multiple node-wekit instances in parallel

Tags: windows, node.js, gulp, multiple-instances, node-webkit

I am working on a desktop application using `Node-webkit`
I tried to run two instances of it by running gulp twice from two different terminals/tabs.
It worked in MAC but faced some issues while trying to do same in windows

While running `Gulp` second time in windows, it gave following error:

[image]

Error: "Cannot Initialise the web database: 2"
Is there any way I can run multiple instances of nodewebkit in windows?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put [`"single-instance": false`](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Manifest-format#single-instance) in your `package.json`.

Comment: Worked for me too, nice and simple. :)